# Access objects in a list, perform a foreach using their properties with F#

Tags: c#, f#, c#-to-f#

I've got a list of objects, to make this question generic lets say I have the object of type 'myType'. myType has two properties x and y, they are both integers. I also have a list of 'myType' objects called 'myList'.

I want to perform something on each object in this list, I'll give an example.

```ml
  override form.OnPaint e = 
      let g = e.Graphics in
      for myType in myList do
      g.FillRectangle(Brushes.Black, x, x, x, x) // instead of x I want to use the values from myType's properties.
```

So in C# I would simply do a

```
foreach (myType x in myList) 
{
    g.FillRectangle(Brushes.Black, x.x, x.y ...etc)
}
```

Whereas now in F# the foreach syntax is different and I'm not sure it can access the specific objects properties like the given example in C#.

Any ideas on how to do this will be greatly appreciated, keep in mind I'm new to F# and still have alot to learn so the syntax is still a bit iffy for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want

```ml
mylist |> Seq.iter (fun x -> g.FillRectangle(Brushes.Black,x.x,x.y,...))
```

Comment: Looks like the right solution but I'm getting this error.

"Type mismatch. Expecting a
    Collections.Generic.List<'a> -> unit    
but given a
    'b list -> unit"    

I was hoping I could just add a |> ignore to ignore the return value but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: `List` here refers to an F# list - which I assumed you were using.  Changing `List` to `Seq` should fix this.

Comment: Yes, may have been a sequence and not a list, my appologies, anyhow thanks for a quick and helpful answer!

Comment: It wasn't actually a `Seq` it is just that `Seq` will work with any type that implements `Ienumerable<'t>` which `System.Collections.Generic.List<'t>` does

Comment: You could can also just use the for..in expression for looping over enumerables without needing a result:
`for x in mylist do g.FillRectangle(Brushes.Black,x.x,x.y,...)`